# Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-databinding, android-espresso-recorder

I am getting the following error when running espresso test `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`

```
> Task :app:fixStackFramesLiveDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:fixStackFramesLiveDebugAndroidTest'.
> Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: classes.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:3.4.1).
  The following types/formats are supported:
    - A String or CharSequence path, for example 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'.
    - A String or CharSequence URI, for example 'file:/usr/include'.
    - A File instance.
    - A Path instance.
    - A Directory instance.
    - A RegularFile instance.
    - A URI or URL instance.
```

`app/build.gradle` contains the following

```
...
android {
  .....
  defaultConfig {
     ...
     testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     ...
  }
  dataBinding {
     enabled = true
  }
}
...
```

Irrespective of espresso dependencies, I am getting the above error. Can someone please help to resolve this issue. I am new to android and espresso.
I am not sure if I had missed out information. Please let know if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this error after updating gradle to 3.4.+ After I downgraded to 3.3.2 I was able to build without any issues.

Comment: changing `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1` worked.

Answer (score 3):

On Android Studio 4.0 canary 4 with Gradle Kotlin DSL enabled, I got the kinda same error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: {dir=libs, include=[*.jar]}.
```

After I changed my build script from

```
dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(Pair("dir", "libs"), Pair("include", listOf("*.jar"))))
}
```

everything works well. WTF.